# Splotches on carpet

Tags: carpet, stain, stain-removal

[image: Splotches on carpet]

Hi, pictured are splotches on my carpet. I have no idea how they got there -- my best guess is that I spilled water at that location one or multiple times and the dirt stuck to the carpet fibers because of that.

My question is how do I get them out?

Answer (score 1):

A few drops of liquid dish soap (I use Dawn because it removes grease and oil really well) in warm water. Dampen the area (do not soak), use a scrub brush, then use a wet/dry vacuum to suck up as much moisture as you can. Place a fan to blow the area for as long as you can to prevent mold/mildew on the carpet and pad underneath. *Then drink your wine out on the patio instead of over the light color carpet.*